# How to render only selected template in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have ~20 yamls in my helm chart + tons of dependencies and I want to check the rendered output of the specific one. `helm template` renders all yamls and produces a hundred lines of code. Is there a way (it would be nice to have even a regex) to render only selected template (by a file or eg. a name).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

From [helm template documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/)

> -s, --show-only stringArray        only show manifests rendered from the given templates

For rendering only one resource use `helm template -s templates/deployment.yaml .`

Comment: One small note. Don't use anything before the "templates" folder.
e.g. if you run ```helm template -s ./templates/deployment.yaml .``` it will fails with error ```Error: could not find template ./templates/deployment.yaml in chart```

Comment: @V.S. true, it depends on the actual helm dir structure, starting from the Charts.yml dir

Comment: Also to note in helm2 the blank template will be rendered as blank but in helm3 it throws the error as `Error: could not find template ./templates/deployment.yaml in chart` , so need to take care when there are if checks in the template . Reference : https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7295#issuecomment-631151740

Comment: How do you do this for a subcharts yaml files?

Comment: @red888 did you manage to do that for a subchart yaml file? I didn't find any way currently

Comment: For a subchart with an alias, you use the alias.  `helm template . --values=myvalues.yaml --show-only charts/(chart alias)/templates/deployment.yaml`.  It's the same path as appears in the `#comment` header when you perform a `helm template` of the entire chart.

Comment: If your template is rendered conditionally based on `{{- if ... }}`, you have to ensure the condition is true. Otherwise you will see `Error: could not find template templates/deployment.yaml in chart`.

Answer (score 5):

Rendering individual yaml files using `helm template` is tricky if chart is inside subdirectory

In case of directory structure as below

```
|app
|-k8s
|--templates
|---deployment.yaml
|---cronjob.yaml
|--values-env1.yaml
|--values-env2.yaml
|--Chart.yaml
```

Now for example, if it's required to generate manifest for `cronjob.yaml` only, the command would be

```
helm template ./app/k8s -s templates/cronjob.yaml -f ./app/k8s/values-env1.yaml
```

Comment: If your template is rendered conditionally based on `{{- if ... }}`, you have to ensure the condition is true. Otherwise you will see `Error: could not find template templates/deployment.yaml in chart`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple charts in one directory:

```
|helm-charts
|-chart1
|--templates
|---deployment.yaml
|--values.yaml
|--Chart.yaml
|...
|- chart2
```

If you want to generate only one file e.g. `chart1/deployment.yaml` using values from file `chart1/values.yaml` follow these steps:

1. Enter to the chart folder:

```
cd chart1
```

2. Run this command:

```
helm template . --values values.yaml -s templates/deployment.yaml --name-template myReleaseName > chart1-deployment.yaml
```

Generated manifest will be inside file `chart1-deployment.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, is to use `yq` to filter output, a bit harder but much powefull (you can filter multiple templates):

Example:

```
helm template . | yq e '. | select(.metadata.name == "*apm*")'
```